# Get the number of bytes needed for a Unicode string

Tags: python, string, unicode, cjk

I have a Korean string encoded as Unicode like `u'정정'`. How do I know how many bytes are needed to represent this string?

I need to know the exact byte count since I'm using the string for iOS push notification and it has a limit on the size of the payload.

`len('정정')` doesn't work because that returns the number of characters, not the number of bytes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to know what *encoding* you want to measure your byte size in:

```
>>> print u'\uC815\uC815'
정정
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815')
2
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815'.encode('UTF-8'))
6
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815'.encode('UTF-16-LE'))
4
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815'.encode('UTF-16'))
6
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815'.encode('UTF-32-LE'))
8
>>> print len(u'\uC815\uC815'.encode('UTF-32'))
12
```

You really want to review the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to fully appreciate the difference between a unicode object and it's byte encoding.

Another excellent article is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), by Joel Spolsky (one of the people behind Stack Overflow).

Comment: How did you know this char is '\uC815'? What encoding is this? I did try utf-8/16/32 and none of them is correct, but '\uC815' seems to be working.

Comment: I have an application called UnicodeChecker that I use for reference, but `C815` is the unicode code point. If you know the UTF-8 or UTF-16 byte sequence, you can *decode* from that to get the unicode character (`'\xEC\xA0\x95'.decode('UTF-8')`). The python prompt is helpful here; python will use it's `unicode_escape` encoding when echoing (not printing) unicode values to the terminal, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The number of bytes required to represent the `unicode` varies depending on the encoding you use.

```
>>> s = u'정정'
>>> len(s)
2
>>> len(s.encode('UTF-8'))
6
>>> len(s.encode('UTF-16'))
6
>>> len(s.encode('UTF-32'))
12
```

If you're going to reuse the encoding result, I recommend encoding it once, then pulling its `len` and reusing the already-encoded result later.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct [standard encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

If you're not, you can always `decodedString = myString.decode('UTF-8')` (substitute UTF-8 with the correct encoding string that you can find from the previous link, if not UTF-8) to get the string in a format where `len(decodedString)` should return the proper number